# How to use fabric-sdk-go to dynamically add organizations (or delete organizations) in an existing fabric network?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-go

I want to use fabric-sdk-go to dynamically add organizations (or delete organizations) to an existing fabric network, but I do n’t know how to implement it. I hope to get everyone ’s help, thank you.